# Custom tooltip with a WS_POPUP dialog

Tags: mfc, tooltip, cdialog

I want to create custom tooltips where I can put any kind of controls. I have derived from CDialog and used the `WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER` styles. I also add the `CS_DROPSHADOW` style in the OnInitDialog to get the tooltip shadow.

Then I manage myself the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` events to show/hide the tooltips.

I display the tooltip using `SetWindowPos` and `SWP_NOACTIVATE` to prevent the parent from becoming inactive and the new dialog from becoming active. But anyway, when I create the dialog using `CDialog::Create` method...the main window becomes inactive...what makes a very bad effect.

So my custion is how can I create a CDialog with the WS_POPUP style without my main window (or the parent window of the dialog) becomening inactive when the new dialog shows up???

Thanks for helping!

Edited: I do not use the WS_VISIBLE style to create the dialog...this this the resource:

```
    IDD_LABEL_TOOLTIP_DLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 100, 9
    STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER
    FONT 8, "Tahoma", 0, 0, 0x0
    BEGIN
       LTEXT           "##################",IDC_TOOLTIP_LBL_TEXT,0,0,99,9
   END
```

The code that display the tooltip is something like that:

```
if(!pTooltipDlg)
{
    pTooltipDlg = new MyCustomTooltipDlg();
    pTooltipDlg->Create( MyCustomTooltipDlg::IDD, this);
}
pTooltipDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

The first time (ie when the create is being call) the main windows lose the focus...the rest of them this ugly effect is not happening...so I am sure is because of the Create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally got it! I just had to return FALSE in the OnInitDialog method to avoid the dialog from being activated.

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 3):

When you create your window, don't set the WS_VISIBLE flag on it. Then you can use ShowWindow with SW_SHOWNA or SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE to make the dialog visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am now using ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE) instead of SetWindowPos and SWP_NOACTIVATE. I didn't realize this option and it is far more smart.

Bad it still not working...I have edited the question with some comments.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `CDialog::Create()` with `WS_VISIBLE` set? It might be that even just calling `Create()` is enough to take focus from the parent. It might also be worth overriding `WM_SETFOCUS` on your tooltip class and *not* calling the base class to make it impossible for the focus to change windows.

Comment: Thanks!

I also tried that. I added this map entry ON_WM_SETFOCUS( ) to my tooltip dialog but the method OnSetFocus is not even being call.

Answer (score 1):

First off, consider using a CWnd rather than a CDialog. This gives you much finer control. And you are not really using any features of the CDialog anyway other than the dialog template; it is not too difficult to dynamically create your controls.

You may also want to consider, in the message handlers, handling OnShowWindow and ensure any show commands are changed to SW_SHOWNA as in Mark Ransom's comment.

Additionally, as a tooltip, it should probably have a NULL parent window.

Comment: I prefer not to change CDialog for CWnd because I want to be able to use any kind of control. In the example I just used a Label but I want to create much more complex dialogs with ActiveX, etc.

I appreciate the other two suggestions but they don't solve the problem.

Thanks anyway!